# How to add a certificate to the last version of restsharp

Tags: certificate, restsharp

It seems that in the last version of this library has changed the way of include a certificate on posting a request.

I use the following:

**var certFile = "xxxxxxx.pfx";**

**X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFile, "pass");**

**request.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { certificate };**

but in the last version the method "ClientCertificates" does not exist anymore.

Does someone know the way of incluing a certificate now?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the [migration guide](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#reference)

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(baseUri) {
    ClientCertificates = ...
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```